# Make any button on the page as a trigger for an asp.net UpdatePanel other than its sibling or child postback controls

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Consider the following code fragment:

```
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="trickyUPTrigger" Text="Tricky Update" />
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="normalUPTrigger" OnClick="normalUPTrigger_Click" Text="Normal Update" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="normalUPTrigger" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="changeableLabel" Text="Change me"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now make the button **with ID of trickyUPTrigger** as the trigger of the UpdatePanel. Or, devise a mechanism (probably... using javascript?) so that when this button is clicked UpdatePanel updates without full page postback.

Comment: It would help if we had some context for this. Is there something you are trying to achieve? I mean, you could write some javascript that does an ajax call to the server and then writes content, or otherwise updates the contents of that panel, but perhaps there is a better way, however, it would help to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The mechanism to make `trickyUPTrigger` a trigger of the UpdatePanel is to add it to the triggers list. Is there a problem doing that?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Your answer works, but please explain the following: *A control that the AsyncPostBackTrigger control references must be in the same naming container as the update panel for which it is a trigger. Triggers that are based on controls in other naming containers are not supported* that made me confused. Thanks...

Comment: Naming containers usually come into play for controls with item templates, like GridView, ListView, etc., and for user controls. In these cases, each item is a naming container. The ID of the controls inside an item are modified from the original ones specified in markup to account for the fact that there can be multiple items (and that each ID must be unique in the page). You can find more explanations in this article: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx.

Comment: @ConnorsFan please edit your answer showing the context you have mentioned with some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the UpdatePanel when clicking on `trickyUPTrigger`, you can add that button to the triggers list:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="normalUPTrigger" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="trickyUPTrigger" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    ...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**UPDATE**

You asked some code examples showing cases with naming containers, a concept that comes into play for databound controls with item templates, like the GridView and the ListView, and for user controls. In the examples below, I use a ListView, where each item is a separate naming container.

If you wanted to trigger an update of your panel from a button in a ListView item template, the trigger would not be found at runtime, and an exception would occur:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="anotherTrigger" runat="server" Text="This trigger cannot be found!" OnClick="anotherTrigger_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="anotherTrigger" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The reverse case (the UpdatePanel in the ListView item template, the trigger button outside of the ListView) does work, according to my tests, which seems to contradict the note that you mention in your comment:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="anotherTrigger" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:Button ID="anotherTrigger" runat="server" Text="This trigger works!" OnClick="anotherTrigger_Click" />
```

Finally, the case where the UpdatePanel and the trigger button are both in the ListView item template also works:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="anotherTrigger" runat="server" Text="This trigger works!" OnClick="anotherTrigger_Click" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="anotherTrigger" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

You can notice that I set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` for the panel in this last example. With this setting, the panel is updated only by its own triggers. If the attribute is set to `UpdateMode="Always"`, the panel is updated not only by his own triggers but also by the triggers of the other UpdatePanels in the page. The default value is `UpdateMode="Always"` (as in your code sample).